# Google plus for android bad access token

Tags: android, api, google-plus, access-token

I been following [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) and [sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) to get access_token of user.

I do get an access token but when using it i am getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

When I am going to [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get) and using they token it works just fine.
Any ideas what am I missing?

This is then URL I am trying.

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={my_api_key}&access_token=my_access_token

Comment: You should post your code so that we can help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These tokens have a 1 hour expiration period.